# How to let the CCSprite handles Touch event?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

I created my OwnCCSprite, and it get the implemented CCStandardTouchDelegate protocol, and ccTouchesBegan event. But it seems not working. When I click the CCSprite, the ccTouchesBegan in the CCLayer is called, but the CCSprite's ccTouchesBegan can't called. How can I detect the CCSprite is being touched in CCLayer / OwnCCSprite? or I need to calculate the touch position, and compares it to the OwnCCSprite positions?

Thz.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the 'TouchesTest' example included with the cocos2d source code.  Specifically take a look at the paddle file.